# Leading digits in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run:

```
select * from jfi.ambitiontempdata limit 2000;
```

My result set is correct but I have an issue with phone numbers. Some of the numbers in my `called_party` and `calling_party` fields are 4-digit extensions, which is fine, and some are normal 10-digit numbers which is also fine, however, some have a leading '1' or other number.

Is there a way to run a query on this table to say `if calling_party or called_party are 11 digits, remove leading digit`?

UPDATE:

This is my current query to match phone numbers in one table to another

```
SELECT ua.*, u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
FROM
 (select a.* FROM jfi.ambitiontempdata a
 inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c on a.called_party = c.phone
 where a.outbound = 1
UNION
select a.* FROM jfi.ambitiontempdata a
inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c on a.calling_party = c.phone
where a.outbound = 0) ua 
INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u
on ua.Extension = u.Extension;
```

jfi.ambitiontempdata phone numbers have some numbers in called_party and calling_party that are the standard 10 digits but some have a leading '1', however, all numbers in my ambition_customer_data have 10 digits.

Comment: use a case to evaluate the length if 11 then take the right 10 characters.  though note the 1 is the country code (US+canada). if you call from outside the US you may need more than 10 digits. and if you call from us to another country you need more than 11.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updating the answer to address the updated question:**
You can grab a substring of the right-most 10 digits (which will only return 4 digits if there are only 4). I'm going to assume that your phone number fields are (var)char fields, and not bigint. If they are stored in a bigint field, then you will need to convert them to a char before manipulating them as a string.

You can use the `RIGHT` function to do this.

```
SELECT ua.*, u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
FROM
 (select a.* FROM jfi.ambitiontempdata a
 inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c on right(a.called_party, 10) = c.phone
 where a.outbound = 1
UNION
select a.* FROM jfi.ambitiontempdata a
inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c on right(a.calling_party, 10) = c.phone
where a.outbound = 0) ua 
INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u
on ua.Extension = u.Extension;
```

Warning: Running the call*_party columns through a function will prevent the optimizer from utilizing an index on those columns. Thus, as your ampitiontempdata table grows, the performance will degrade.

Ideally you should have the same phone number stored in your ampition_customer_data table, or have a separate 10-character column in your ambitiontempdata table. Another solution might be to have a seperate table with a phone number and an ID, and then just reference that ID in your tables, instead of the full phone number.

Comment: Apologies, while you were adding this I was putting an update to my question. I understand this approach but would I be able to incorporate that into the existing query that I just posted in the update? Basically stripping the leading character from the numbers in my ambitiontempdata table and THEN matching to the other table?

Comment: And to confirm, your select statement works perfectly, as does my existing query, I just need to combine them somehow

Comment: @TomN.  you just need to replace `a.called_party` on the join of the first query in the union  with the `right(convert(called_party, char(11)), 10)`  and similar for the second select in the union.`on a.calling_party` with `on right(convert(calling_party, char(11)), 10)`  However this does invalidate index use.  so on a large table expect slower performance; but it should work.

Comment: @xQbert has pretty much said everything I was typing. The major concern with doing this join is that it won't use the index. I'll update the answer. Thanks xQbert

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(calling_party, LEN(calling_party) - 1) AS calling_party_trimmed
SELECT RIGHT(called_party, LEN(called_party) - 1) AS called_party_trimmed
```

To borrow another person's explanation: To explain, RIGHT takes 2 arguments - the string (or column) to operate on, and the number of characters to return (starting at the "right" side of the string). LEN returns the length of the column data, and we subtract one so that our RIGHT function leaves the leftmost character "behind".

Comment: Good methodology, but it misses the question a little bit. This simply removes the first character, rather than trimming the value down to 10 or fewer characters. The danger with using `LEN(calling_party)-1` instead of hard coding a length of "10", is that it assumes the column values will always be 11 characters long.  A country code might be two digits long, making it 12 characters (eg 442071234567), or it might be a 4 digit extension.